# Building R from source

Tags: r, build, cran

I have strange problem as usual while building R from source.
I used these recommendations from cran: `https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/howto-R-4.3.html`

So, I patched `Makefile.win` and `MkRules.rules`:

MkRules.rules

```
USE_ATLAS ?= YES
ATLAS_PATH ?= /c/Repository/AMD/WinLibs
EOPTS ?= -O3 -march=native -mtune=native -mfpmath=both -mfma
```

Makefile.win

```
-L../../../$(IMPDIR) -lR  -L"$(ATLAS_PATH)" -fopenmp -lamdblas -lamdlapack
```

I got an error:

```
gcc -shared -O2 -Wall -O3 -march=native -mtune=native -mfpmath=both -mfma -s -static-libgcc -o tools.dll tmp.def text.o init.o Rmd5.o md5.o signals.o install.o getfmts.o http.o gramLatex.o gramRd.o pdscan.o ../../../gnuwin32/dllversion.o -LC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 -LC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -L../../../../bin/x64 -lR
installing 'sysdata.rda'
make[4]: *** [../../../share/make/basepkg.mk:151: sysdata] Error 127
make[3]: *** [Makefile.win:22: all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile.win:32: R] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:18: all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:399: distribution] Error 2
```

MSYS2 always run in administrator mode.

Without any patches R building fails with the same reason.

Could anyone explain me the problem?

System: Windows 11 Pro, AMD Ryzen 5950X.

RTools is `rtools43-5863-5818.exe`

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate on the R-devel mailing list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554330/user2554330 How to do this?

Comment: See https://www.r-project.org/mail.html .

Comment: @user2554330 Amazingly, R-SIG-windows is not listed there.  https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-windows

Comment: @MikaelJagan. I didn’t know there was such a list. The advice was to post on “R-devel”.  Most Qs from Windows users go to R-help , but Qs about compiling R are directed to R-devel.

Comment: @IRTFM R-devel? How to post on it, could you explain me, pls?

Comment: It’s all explained on the R-project page for mailing lists. I know it’s there because I looked at it yesterday. I think it would be a waste of time to duplicate that here. Just subscribe, read the R FAQ, read the posting guide and the admin documents and post if needed.

Comment: Damn, I don't understand  how to post by the link above, guys. ((